# Are you required to cross the finish line on a bike?

Tags: racing

Suppose you get a flat 100m-1km (or some distance that you can sprint/run) from the finish line. Can you leave your bike and run the remaining distance to the finish line? Or are you required to carry your bike while running? Or are you required to cycle across the finish line (i.e. wait for a service car to come fix your bike)?

Comment: Note that, in pro racing, they don't fix punctures during the race: they replace the complete wheel and tyre and fix it later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[UCI regulation 1.2.109](http://www.uci.org/docs/default-source/rules-and-regulations/part-i--general-organisation-of-cycling-as-a-sport.pdf?sfvrsn=b6f5c2e4_46):

> The rider may cross the finish line on foot, provided that has his bicycle with him.

Note that "his bicycle" may be a teammate's bike or a neutral service bike.

Comment: If only I'd read 9 regulations further :-)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I can imagine you were tired after reading 1.2.100 of them already. :-)

Comment: Well that opens another can of worms, doesn't it! What is a bicycle? I mean, how much of it do you have to have? Matching the starting weight? Complete with the chain? A bike without a chain is pretty useless, but I can easily think of a situation where your chain snaps and drops, and if you stop to fetch it you risk losing. Am I being picky? Well, you started it under the answer from @ArgentiApparatus :-) On a serious note I'm sure there were precedents where this rule was subject of appeals etc.

Comment: I think it can be just any bike. Gerrie Knetemann once got a puncture close to the finish of a race, he borrowed a bike from a farmer along the road and rode the last few kilometers on that.

Answer (score 4):

What constitutes a 'finish' will depend on the race organizing body and regulations and rules.

For the races organized under the Union Cyliste Internationale (UCI) rules, at least a partial answer can be found in the [UCI Cycling Regulations, Part 1: General Organisation Of Cycling as a Sport](http://www.uci.org/docs/default-source/rules-and-regulations/part-i--general-organisation-of-cycling-as-a-sport.pdf?sfvrsn=b6f5c2e4_46):

> 1.2.100 The finish occurs at the instant that the tyre of the front wheel
>   meets the vertical plane rising from the starting edge of the finishing line.

So, the bike has to cross the line. Doing a quick search I did not find anything in the general rules about how the rider may propel the bike (riding, pushing carrying etc).

Comment: Teeeeeechnically, 1.2.100 would be satisfied by the cyclist carrying just their front wheel. (Or even just their front tyre, though it would take a while to remove a tubular from the wheel so that seems less likely.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby according to the rule, could I roll my front wheel down the road crossing the finish line ahead of me?

Comment: @GaryBak Ha! Yes. Though both of our cunning plans are shot down by 1.2.109, as quoted in my answer.